# Question about password parameter not get value in a Razor page only while testing on Android and IPhone

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, blazor

I am really puzzled about this question, I did try to make just a simple login form like in the example in this webpage:

https://www.blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/36

If I try to execute the example code in a windows machine checking the code in Login.cshtml.cs when the call happen to

```
 public async Task<IActionResult>
    OnGetAsync(string paramUsername, string paramPassword)
```

I can see the value of the variable I insert in the input control and working fine.
As soon as I try to do the same while the example is working and connect to my server from a mobile and try to debug the example I see that the paramPassword has no value at all and just return null.

The logincontrol page is pretty simple:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <b>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</b>
        <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
           href="/logout?returnUrl=/"
           target="_top">Logout</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <input type="text"
               placeholder="User Name"
               @bind="@Username" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="password"
               placeholder="Password"
               @bind="@Password" />
        <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
           href="/login?paramUsername=@encode(@Username)&paramPassword=@encode(@Password)"
           target="_top">Login</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

but it's kinda puzzle me on why do a GetAsync to the razor page work on a windows machine but not on mobile ? Thank you for the help

Comment: you should probably POST that info.  (GETs tend to show up in logs, and with POST you can add anti-forgery)  I'm guessing that'll solve the issue, too, since you won't need JS to read the password field.  Does the URL in the link contain the parameter?  Also, is the field being auto-filled?  (it may protect auto-filled values in type=password)

Comment: to further the GETs in logs point:  even your DB shouldn't be storing passwords in a reversible format... you probably store a hash or a token, which can't be reversed into a plain text password...  if server is hacked, the logs may now be exposing them.  POST bodies are usually not written to logs.  I think you'd have to specifically add that sort of functionality

Comment: Thank you pcalkins, sorry I never add further details but yes on the other project I have hashed password of user that have to be tested with the one sent by the form. If you download the example and try to execute it you see that he use a href ro enter link of the login.cshtml.cs and there is made the check on the password. So maybe have to be changed the method OnPostAsync(string paramUsername, string paramPassword) and collect the post data sent to the login.cshtml.cs but what puzzle me is WHY on mobile device it's not working while on windows yes ?

Comment: I don't know, but I suspect it's not allowing JS access to password type inputs.  Maybe just for auto-filled ones?  You could test that by chaning to <input type="text"... and seeing if that does go through.

Comment: should probably remove the placeholder attribute too.  Doesn't seem useful and if it's submitted would be empty (which by default asp.net will convert to null)  Auto-fill in that case may not trigger change on phones, which might interfere with binding.

Comment: come to think of it auto-fill, whether it's a phone or desktop may not trigger change until the user clicks on the input and loses focus.  It won't fire onchange... (though I believe it would trigger oninput... so you could add a handler for oninput...)

Comment: Already did, same error it's not about the input type="text" I guess it's about the controller getasync but not sure why only mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please kindly check the debug steps below, it will help us know the issue.

I agree with [pcalkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744568/pcalkins)'s comment, when the password input box loses focus, the href value of the A tag is not updated immediately, if I don't inspect the element then it's null, in my gif, I first type `222`, then the second time I don't inspect the element, and I enter another 2 numbers again, and after committing, the breakpoint on the server side only shows `222`.

[image]

We can fix the issue by using `@bind:event="oninput"` and `@bind:event="oninput"`. Here is the sample code.

```
<NotAuthorized>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="User Name"
           @bind="@Username"
           @bind:event="oninput" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="password"
           placeholder="Password"
           @bind="@Password"
           @bind:event="oninput" />
    <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
       href="/login?paramUsername=@encode(Username)&paramPassword=@encode(Password)"
       target="_top">Login</a>

</NotAuthorized>
```

**Modified effects**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much with the clear explanation I never know of this behavior so I will check that too.

Comment: hi @jason I never inspect more the issue because at the end I had to change the method to Post instead of Get and had to work with controllers, anyway as you gave me more clue on the issue I will accept the answer. Best regards.